# Why i get plus three on my index when i click on load more button

Tags: javascript

//Fetch Posts

```
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    //Content load function start here
let count = 12;
function contentLoad() {
  let showPosts = "";
  let modalOutput = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    // First on load show 12 posts as limited, after that can load more on button 

        showPosts += `
          <ul class='list-group my-4'>
            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>ID: </span>  ${
              data[i].id
            }</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Title: </span>  ${
              data[i].title
            }</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Post: </span>  ${data[
              i
            ].body
              .split(" ")
              .splice(0, 3)
              .join(" ")}</li>
          </ul>`;
        document.querySelector(".post-content").innerHTML = showPosts;
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
```

// Add a listener to all posts to open modal when clicking

```
        document.querySelectorAll("ul").forEach((element, index) => {
          element.addEventListener("click", function () {
            document
              .getElementById("close")
              .addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
              });
      // Here we get data for modal
            fetch(
              `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${data[index].userId}`
            )
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((dataUser) => {
                modalOutput = ` 
                      <ul class='list-group my-4'>
                          <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>ID:</span>  ${data[index].id}</li>
                          <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>FullName:</span>  ${dataUser.name}</li>
                          <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Title:</span>  ${data[index].title}</li>
                          <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Post:</span>  ${data[index].body}</li>
                          <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Location:</span>  ${dataUser.address.city}</li>
                    </ul>`;

                document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
                document.querySelector(".modal-data").innerHTML = modalOutput;
                fetch(
                  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=${data[index].id}`
                )
                  .then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((dataComment) => {

   // Here I show a modal with specific data

                    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
                    document.querySelector(".modal-data").innerHTML = ` 
                            <ul class='list-group my-4'>
                            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>ID:</span>  ${data[index].id}</li>
                            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>User Name:</span> ${dataUser.name}</li>
                            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Title:</span>  ${data[index].title}</li>
                            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Post:</span>  ${data[index].body}</li>
                            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Location:</span>  ${dataUser.address.city}</li>
                            <li class='list-group-item'><span class='fw-bold'>Company:</span>  ${dataUser.company.name}</li>`;

    // Here i loop odd comments

                    let comments = "";
                    // document.getElementById("loading-modal").style.display =
                    //   "none";

                    for (let c = 0; c < dataComment.length; c++) {
                      if (dataComment[c].id % 3 == 0) {
                        comments += `
                                    <ul class='item-group'>
                                    <li class='list-group-items'> <span class='fw-bold'>Id:</span> ${dataComment[c].id}</li>
                                    <li class='list-group-items'> <span class='fw-bold'>Email:</span> ${dataComment[c].email}</li>
                                    <li class='list-group-items'> <span class='fw-bold'>Comment:</span> ${dataComment[c].body}</li>
                                    </ul>`;
                        document.querySelector(`.modal-comments`).innerHTML =
                          comments;
                      }
                    }
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    throw console.log(error);
                  });
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                throw console.log(error);
              });
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

// Load more posts on the button click, the problem starts when I try
// third time to load posts, they load posts but the id doesn't match
// When I click on a post they open me modal, but the ID doesn't match, they add 3 on ID (Index)

```
        document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  count = count + 12;

  if (count > 96) {
    document.querySelector(".btn").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "block";
  }

  contentLoad();
});
  .catch((error) => {
    throw console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: This makes no sense: `dataLimit = data.slice(dataLimit, (count += 12));` The first argument to `slice()` has to be a number, but `dataLimit` is an array.

Comment: It's my mistake. I put the wrong code. That is something that I try. I will edit now